# Stuck between pthread_create and static function - How do I move forward?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I'm writing a simple media player program in C++ and I am trying to make it multi-threaded.  I want the "MediaPlayer" object to be running in it's own thread as soon as it starts (as shown in the `main.cpp` below).  But if a user decides to play a playlist by entering "PP " in the console I want the media player to spawn off another thread that plays all the songs in the playlist. But doing so requires me to make the function "ThreadPlay" to static. But making "ThreadPlay" static creates problems for me because it doesn't let me call MediaPlayer::play() !

How do I get around this?

main.cpp

```
void * ThreadMediaPlayer(void *threadid)
{
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);

    MediaPlayer myPlayer;
    myPlayer.start();

    return NULL;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t playerThread;
    int rc1 = pthread_create(&playerThread, NULL, ThreadMediaPlayer, (void *)0);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

MediaPlayer.h

```
struct UserData {
    long threadId;
    string playlistName;
};
```

MediaPlayer.cpp

```
void MediaPlayer::start(){
    // get commands

    while (true){
        string command;

        cout << "(CS) Create Song <song name> <length in seconds>" << endl;
        cout << "(CP) Create Playlist <playlist name> " << endl;
        cout << "(A)  Add songs to playlist <playlist name> <song name>" << endl;
        cout << "(PP) Play Playlist <Playlist name> " << endl;
        cout << "(Q)uit" << endl;

        cin >> command;

        if (command == "Q"){
            break;
        }
        parseAndProcessCommand(command);

    }
}


 static void * ThreadPlay(void * userData)
{
    long tid;
    tid = ((struct UserData *)userData)->threadId;
    string playlistName = ((struct UserData *)userData)->playlistName;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);

    play( playlistName    );

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `this` as the last argument to `pthread_create`, and then your static function casts the `void *` to your class type and calls a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd just use `std::thread` as it has suitable constructors and is easily used. Assuming you don't use that because you don't have C++11, you'll find that there is actually another problem you haven't even noticed: `pthread_create()` takes an `extern "C"` function. Conveniently, it also takes a user data pointer as argument: you'd use that point to your object.

That is, your thread entry function would look like this:

```
extern "C"
void* entry(void* data) {
     static_cast<MediaPlayer*>(data)->start();
     return 0;
}
```

... and you'd call `pthread_create()` something like this:

```
MediaPlayer player(/* probably some ctor arguments */);
pthread_create(&playerThread, 0, entry, &player);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the object pointer of MediaPlayer into your UserData, and create a non-static version of ThreadPlay. Within your existing static ThreadPlay, you use the MediaPlayer object pointer in UserData to invoke the non-static version of ThreadPlay.